# Database States Touching States - SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database, state

Theory question here.. I am trying to determine if there is a good way to know given any US state if there is a way to know what states are "touching" that state.

`Select NeighborState from MyStateList where BaseState = 'TN'` would tell me

```
NC
SC
GA
AL
MS
AR
MO
KY
VA
```

Does such a source of data exist or is this just a brute force type thing where I just create the entries for all 50 states.

I am asking this question because by doing this in a where clause I am going to cut down a LOT of possible matches and I would like to try and implement this.

Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: You could always make a new table that has a list of states along with all the states touching them (`stateID1   |   stateID2`) so you would have entries like `TN   |   NC` and `TN   |   SC`.  Whether or not that exists somewhere, I'm not sure but I would bet the internet has it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with only US only I would just create a table with the relationships for border. We are dealing with 50 states and only a few hundred or so bordering. Would be simple and quick to create that setup.